# C# DDD without EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, domain-driven-design

I'm starting with DDD and I'm having one doubt. Suppose this classes (I'm using C# with Net Framework 4.7):

```
public class Address : ValueObject
{
    // Properties.
    public string Street { get; }
    public int Number { get; }


    public Address(string street, int number)
    {
        Street = street;
        Number = number;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return Street;
        yield return Number;
    }
}

public class Customer : IAggregateRoot
{
    // Properties.
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public Address Address { get; protected set; }


    public Customer(string name, Address address)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) throw new Exception(nameof(name));

        Name = name;
        Address = address ?? throw new Exception(nameof(address));
    }

    // For database purpose.
    protected Customer()
    {

    }
}
```

I have the interface ICustomerRepository and as infraestructure, I need to use raw SQL (SQL Server), I mean, no EF, NHibernate, etc. The approach I'm using within the repository implementation is to define a class "CustomerBuilder" who inherits from Customer, to be able to access protected fields. Is there any other way to achieve this? Because for each entity I need to load, I have to create a builder and repeat constructors and variable mapping.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can you not use an ORM? That's such a restrictive requirement.

Comment: @DavidG we are refactoring our app and we already have all implemented using raw SQL queries. I know that using an ORM is a lot easier, but I want to know what happen in our case that we need to keep using raw SQL.

Comment: Nothing will "happen", it's just a lot harder. I would suggest using Dapper since that is a good halfway between something like EF and raw SQL. It will let you use your existing queries and map them into C# objects.

Comment: @DavidG I know it's harder, but I really want to know how to implement this situation. I can't find any example without ORM 

Comment: You could use a generic wrapper to access non-public properties and methods, but you'd lose intellisense as you'd have to use field, property and method names instead.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single answer to your question. I can think of the following solutions:

1. For each aggregate, create a "state DTO", a class with properties exposing the information you want to persist from your aggregate. Then create either a factory method or a constructor in your aggregate class that accepts this state DTO. Your repositories would new up the state DTO and pass it to the aggregate constructor/factory.
2. Use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/), similar to point one, you'd need a DTO to initially load the information from the database. Then, instead of passing it to the aggregate to manually map to the aggregate's properties, use AutoMapper to automagically do the mapping for you.
3. Build your own mapper using [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). You can create a series of helper methods to make it easy to map properties with private setters by name and type.

From the 3 solutions above, I think number 1 is the cleanest, but it doesn't save you much typing compared to what you are doing already. Option number 3 will be harder to set up, but once done, you should be able to create new repositories without much overhead. But effectively you are writing something that you can get for free by installing a nugget package.

Comment: Coupling Automapper with your domain logic is very dangerous. Automapper have been designed to map DTOs not objects with complex construction logic and value objects. By doing so, you will have to make compromise on the encapsulation of your aggregate in order to make Automapper happy.

Comment: @MaximeGélinas in any way I am proposing to couple AutoMapper to the domain logic. The domain logic wouldn't even have a reference to AutoMapper nor know about it in any way. Automapper was literally built for these scenarios and there are several extension libraries for this, being https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data probably useful to implement what I am proposing. Also, a repository should not have to deal with "complex construction logic" nor any logic whatsoever.

Comment: Jimmy Boggard specifically said that Automapper is for DTOs and nothing else.

Comment: @MaximeGélinas I'd say this is misquoting him. He was arguing against mapping user/API input to domain objects. But in any case, a quote is not an argument. All ORMs do mapping between DB columns to (domain) object properties. Automapper uses pretty much the same techniques that ORMs use so it can be used for the same purpose. It won't add any coupling as you say. It just needs to set the domain object properties to the values coming from the DB and it can do it just fine. That said, Dapper (as a light wait library) is a better fit for this, but the OP is asking how to do it without an ORM.

Comment: Using an ORM/automapper to build your domain aggregate is the bad part. I'm not saying it wont work, but by doing so you're forced the make compromise about design/encapsulation of your aggregates. Splitting your domain entities from your persistence layer is an important part of DDD. Aggregate should be built from aggregate factories.

Comment: @FrancescCastells from my basic knowledge about DDD, is a good practice to involve a DTO as part of the domain? As I can see, apply DDD without an ORM seems a liitle difficult.

Comment: @MaximeGélinas "you're forced the make compromise about design/encapsulation of your aggregates" Quite the opposite. ORMs can map to the internal state of a class. Without this, you have to expose a way of modifying the internal state by code, which is what breaks the encapsulation. "Splitting your domain entities from your persistence layer is an important part of DDD", I don't think DDD cares about this, but again your domain entities don't know about the ORM. "Aggregate should be built from aggregate factories", only to create them, not to hydrate them from storage (if you can avoid it).

Comment: Note that there is a big difference in how your business logic creates and modifies an aggregate and how the persistence layer rehydrates an aggregate from persistence. Your business layer can create an Order in the Created state and then execute order.Submit() and the State will be set to Submitted. Your business logic cannot directly set the state to Submitted. But when your persistence layer needs to load the order from storage, it has to be able to set the state property to Submitted without having to Submit the order again (which would, for example, change the SubmitedTime)

Comment: @tincho87 "is a good practice to involve a DTO as part of the domain", there are different ways where DTOs are involved with your domain objects. For example, executing business operations on a domain object many times requires parameters and they can be passed with the form of a DTO. Like, Order.AddLine(OrderLineDto orderLine). Or as in my suggestion number 1, you can define a StateDto used to create the aggregate in a specific state.

Comment: @FrancescCastells so instead of accessing directly internal entity variables, I can define a constructor that accepts a StateDTO which is provided by the infrastructure layer, right? And StateDTO would be part of the domain, as a helper class.

Comment: @FrancescCastells I agree with everything you said in theory, but in practice using automapper or an orm to rehydrate aggregates is a nightmare. My team have choosen this path since a year now and we have encounter a lot of specific problems. The biggest one is immutability and change tracking. An event-driven + snapshot approach is a lot easier.

Comment: @tincho87 exactly.

Comment: @MaximeGélinas yes, of course, every approach has its downsides. I actually prefer to store aggregates as json documents. Event sourcing is good, but it also has downsides. If you do snapshots and forget the previous events you can overcome some of them, like having to maintain compatibility with events from several years ago or complying with GDPR, but you still have issues like always having to project a read model somewhere. I guess events+snapshots is similar to my option 1 (snapshot), plus running the delta of events.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and I've ended up using the Memento pattern. I've had to make some compromises, but iat the end the code works flawlessly and it's definitely simple to maintain.

I explain how is designed.
In the domain layer I've and entity and a memento classes. The entity exposes just the domain functions, plus (here is the compromise) an extra function that allows to export itself to the memento.
Whenever I need to use the content of the entity (normally inside the infrastructure layer) I call the function that returns the memento from my entity. Here, to simplify my work, I have another memento (that extends the original one and could be built using the original one or with the data from the infrastructure layer) that exposes a set of functions useful in that particular infrastructure context. So for example, for the persistence I've all the functions that build each type of map used by the SQL. The other function gets the SQL results and stores inside in the format used by the memento.
Mementos are built in a way that's hard to build them outside the contexts where they're used.

I know that it's more code then what's normally someone writes with a ORM and also doesn't use any fancy functionality like reflection, but it's fast to test, it's working, it's doing what I expect and I don't have to play around with configuration files. It's just pre programming.

Comment: The memento pattern is a great fit for this, but it still create a tight coupling between domain and persistence. You will end up having to add some fields in your aggregate just for persistence purposes which is bad. You should consider using domain events in pair with the memento pattern to gather data that need to be saved but doesn't belong into your aggregate.

Comment: Not really. In my implementation no field has been created or adapted to support the memento class. Moreover, I've different mementos (for persistence into db, for persistence into an index etc) that extends the default one and are used with custom functions inside the infrastructure layer. What's true is that I expose a memento from the domain to the outs world, but it's a functional requirement that comes from using the sql directly.

Comment: @MaximeGélinas Hi! But what about gathering data from db to fill domain entity? That's where I'm struggling to get a solution without using any ORM.

Comment: @tincho87 That is where, the memento pattern take place. The repository map the data from db into a snapshot object that you can load into your aggregate using the memento pattern. Here is an example: https://github.com/maximegel/stock-trader/blob/master/StockTrader.Portfolios.Persistence/PortfolioDbRepository.cs#L34